# Apache variable to get the path of the site

Tags: apache-2.2

I am using the following line into the apache configuration  to get the accesslog via the syslog:

```
  CustomLog "|/usr/bin/logger -p local1.notice -t apache-mycompany" common
```

However, there is another setup where apache doesn't use vhosts, there is just a 00default file(front nginx does the vhosting) and i want to be able to distinguish. Is there any way to add a variable in the -t argument that distinguishes each site access? I guess it can be the URL or the folder that holds the file.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
CustomLog "|/usr/bin/logger -p local1.notice -t %f" common
```

for the file path, or

```
CustomLog "|/usr/bin/logger -p local1.notice -t %U" common
```

for the URL.  See [Custom Log Formats](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats) in the Apache docs for a list of all the possible substitution strings.

Comment: Maybe you could elaborate it more.